# xml parsing listview in android like category,subcategory

Tags: java, android, android-listview

i have to develop android listview using xml parsing.,

Am getting xml feed from mysql server.the product is added day to day activities.

Here i need 3 kind of listview:

```
1st view:   Category
2nd view:  SubCategory
3rd view:   Product
```

In fistview have to display Categoryname alone.

From my xml feed **1st view** have to display

**Categoryname** alone

In **2nd view**:

Have to display **subcategoryname** belonging to Categoryname.

In **3nd View**:

Have to display Product Name and Price belongs to subcategoryname.

This is my 1st view code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static final String URL =http://api1.sfsfsfsf.com/dev/categories/?fields=&categoryid=3&access_token=bfb787a6e

        static String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";

       static final String KEY_TITLE = "categoryName";
        static final String KEY_SUBCATE = "categoryId";

 ListView lview3;
 LazyAdapter adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CATEGORY);

        // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>   ();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);


            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
           map.put(KEY_SUBCATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SUBCATE));             
        songsList.add(map);
        }
    lview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
    lview3.setAdapter(adapter);

    lview3.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
           HashMap<String, String> map = songsList.get(position);
            Intent in = new Intent(
                    MainActivity.this,
                     com.example.androidcartxml.SubCate.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, map.get(KEY_TITLE));
            in.putExtra(KEY_SUBCATE, map.get(KEY_SUBCATE));
               }  


     });

    }

         }
```

Here i have displayed category list in 1st view.also pass the categoryid from 1st view to 2nd view.

This is my 2nd view code:

```
       public class SubCate extends Activity {
         String mTitle;

         static final String URL = "http://api1.sfsfsff.com/dev/categories/?fields=&categoryid="+mTitle+"&access_token=bfb787a6e11";
            static String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";

              static final String KEY_TITLE = "categoryName";
             static final String KEY_NAME ="categoryId";
             static final String KEY_SUBCATE = "categoryId";
 ListView lview3;
 ListViewCustomAdapter adapter;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subcate);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    //String s= getIntent().getStringExtra("orderid");
    mTitle = b.getString(KEY_SUBCATE);
    TextView grandtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subcate);
    grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + mTitle );
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

   // String key = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CATEGORY);

        // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key =&gt; value

            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            songsList.add(map);
        }
    lview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(this, songsList);
    lview3.setAdapter(adapter);

    lview3.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = songsList.get(position);
            Intent in = new Intent(
                    SubCate.this,
                     com.example.androidcartxml.Catalogue.class);

            in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, map.get(KEY_TITLE));
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, map.get(KEY_NAME));
        //  in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, map.get(KEY_THUMB_URL));
            //in.putExtra(KEY_PRICE, map.get(KEY_PRICE));
            startActivity(in);
        }  

     });
```

In 2nd view have displayed categoryid value get it from 1st activity.but i have to mention that id to link means doesn't getting subcategory list.please give me some solution for these.

FOR EG:

take this is my subcategory link:

[http://api1.sfsfsffsf.com/dev/categories/?fields=&categoryid=10&access_token=bfb787a6e1][1]

means have displayed subcategory list.

Here i have to pass that category id 10(categoryid=10) from first to second and save it i textview.

```
    mTitle = b.getString(KEY_SUBCATE);
    TextView grandtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subcate);
       grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + mTitle );
```

I have to call these mTitle value on my link means it is not displayed on subcategorylist.please help me.

[http://api1.sfsfsff.com/dev/categories/?fields=&categoryid="+mTitle+"&access_token=bfb787a6][2]

whats wrong in my code.how can **call that categoryid to my url**.please give me solution for these.

**EDIT:**

This is my url:

[http://api1.sfsfsfsf.com/dev/categories/?fields=&categoryid=10&access_token=bfb787a6e][3]

I have mentioned directly categoryid=10 means have disaplyed all product.

But I have to change this url like:

[http://api1.sfsfsf.com/dev/categories/?fields=&categoryid="+mTitle+"&access_token=bfb787a6e17][4]

Nw i have changed my url like categoryid="+mTitle+" means not displayed all products.

mTitle value is getting from my pervious activity.

whats wrong in my code.

my mTitle value is 10.i have to wrote the code like means

`grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + mTitle );`

its displayed mTitle value successfully.

`grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + URL );` means gave me null value

Comment: Take Listview in 2nd view same as first view

Comment: @DipakKeshariya In 2nd view:

I have to click Books on my 1st view means ll go to next activity have to display on 2nd view

Internet
Software
Or

I have to click CD-DVD-Video on my 1st view means ll go to 2nd view also have to display
But i have to run the app and  click Books means am getting all subcategories displayed on 2nd view.
CD
DVD
Audio

Comment: I already send you source code about this.

Comment: Check my update answer and reply me it's helpful to you or not.

Comment: @user1897014 Sorry Dear here i just mention how to read the xml response using sax parser.now you change your requirement.ok thanks for feedback.But here i advice u that it's your chalenge that how to display iin seperate list. again thanks for feedback.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here i have called URL first then only declared mTitle value.thats why i have faced problem here.

Now i got the solution:

I have declared mTitle first afterthat only have called URL like below.

```
 mTitle = b.getString(KEY_SUBCATE);

 URL = "http://api1.sfsfsffsf.com/dev/categories/?fields=&categoryid=" + mTitle +       "&access_token=bfb787a";
```

Answer (score 1):

i advice use sax parser instead of dom parser.

this link helpful to you.
[read this.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/127758/XML/Difference-SAX-DOM)

Comment: give me sample parsing in android listview

Comment: Sorry Dear be lated but here your code to slove your problem.          http://pastie.org/5579468

Comment: now only i got the clear requirment.please read my updated question and give me solution for these.

Comment: Sorry Dear here i just mention how to read the xml response using sax parser.now you change your requirement.ok thanks for feedback.But here i advice u that it's your chalenge that how to display iin seperate list. again thanks for feedback..